# How to benchmark gRPC services properly?

Tags: python, c++, performance, benchmarking, grpc

Now we're using gRPC to implement the services in both Python and C++. We want to benchmark and get the performances between them.

Currently we're writing Python client with multiple threads and multiple processes. But we could not read the bottlenecks of CPU, memory, network traffic or disk IO. I'm not sure if it's related to the Python `GIL`.

What's the proper way to benchmark this without re-writing the tools? We still have a lot of work to get the 99% or 99.9% latency. Do communities have any tool or project for this and what's your experience?